# How to bypass a URL shortener with advertising?

Tags: browser, script, opera, userscripts

I'm looking for a script to bypass links provided by the website [1short.us](http://1short.us) to 
get the download link directly.

For example: http://1short.us/368527

Is there any way to do that?

I found this user script, but it can't bypass the second page.

```
// @namespace      TecHPrO
// @description    Short Script Bypass u can add any site using this script
// @include        http://1short.us/*
// ==/UserScript==


var n=location.pathname;
var exp= /m1.php/;
var x= n.search(exp);

if (x != -1)
{
var l=document.getElementsByName('groovybtn1')[0];
var s = l.getAttribute('onclick');
var s1= s.split("(\'");
var s2= s1[1];
var s3= s2.split("\',\'");
var s4= s3[0];
window.location= s4;}

else {
var p=location.href;
var c=p.split("http://");
var c1=c[0];
var c2=c[1].split("/");
var c3=c2[0];
var c4=c2[1]
window.location="http://"+c3+"/m1.php?id="+c4;
}
```

I've found a second user script, but it appends `','name','800','800','yes');return%20false` to the final URL.

Here's the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
    // @name        1short.us
    // @namespace   1short.us/*
    // @include     http://1short.us/*
    // @version     1
    // ==/UserScript==

/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */

/* Contents of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js */

    //this is the place to work in lets test
//"NewWindow('mediafire_fix.php?url=http://www.mediafire.com/?a0unhxiksg47ejg','name','800','600','yes');return false"
var link =location.href;
link=link.replace("http://1short.us/","");
//alert(link);
var link2="";
$.get("http://1short.us/m1.php?",{'id':link} ,function(data){
    link2=$(data).find(':button').attr('onclick');
    link2=link2.replace("NewWindow('","");
    link2=link2.replace("','name','800','600','yes');return false","");
    location.href=link2
 });
```

Comment: If the site wants you to go to the download link through some previous page, it is at least rude to bypass that.

Comment: @vonbrand: You're still opening the 1short sites, just skipping them automatically rather than manually. It's about as rude as using an ad blocker. The ad popup and the fact that you're *forced* to open the download in a new browser window (not even a new tab)... now that's rude, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user script itself is working fine, but the headers are incomplete.

The first lines should be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @namespace      TecHPrO
// @description    Short Script Bypass u can add any site using this script
// @include        http://1short.us/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

Note that the first line is missing. This causes the headers to be ignored, so the script gets applied to *all* websites. To work properly, it should be restricted to sites of the `1short.us` domain.

As it is, the user script redirects from `1short.us/368527` to `1short.us/m1.php?id=368527`, and from there to `turbobit.net/aveyd9fs89oc.html`. So far, so good. It should stop here.

However, due to the missing header, the `else` block of the `if` statement gets executed again, and the script redirects to `turbobit.net/m1.php?id=aveyd9fs89oc.html`. This results in a 404.

---

The second user script does not work since 1short – apparently – changed the size of their new browser window. Any change to the website will might render a user script useless.

In this case, the line

```
link2=link2.replace("','name','800','600','yes');return false","");
```

is supposed to get rid of the unwanted part of the URL, but the actual URL finishes with:

```
','name','800','800','yes');return false
```

Changing that line of the user script to

```
link2=link2.replace("','name','800','800','yes');return false","");
```

(i.e., replacing `600` with `800`) will fix it.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't clear to me from your answer. (You might edit that bit in.)

Comment: Thank u very much Dennis for ur respond,
but, as I told u before I couldn't bypass the second page after all
(from "1short.us/m1.php?id=368527" to "turbobit......"

however, I had found another script that get the job done but, with a little bug .

after bypassing pages successfully , this is last result :

( http://turbobit.net/aveyd9fs89oc.html','name','800','800','yes');return%20false )

by your experience, how could i fix it ?

Comment: I have tested the script with the modified header in the latest version of Google Chrome, and it works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: thanks again my friend 4 ur fast and useful responds..

I am using opera 12.14 ,
I will try it on chrome wishing it'll work well .

Comment: Perfect Dennis , u r greaaaaaaat >>>

after my successful trial on firfox , i thought that it could work well if i use the "violent.monkey" opera extension to install the script < and guess what....it works Perfect !!
thaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot Dennis for your Valuable help

Comment: @Dennis wish i could do more than that...
actually you did help me to bypass at least 8 other Domains!! 

by the way, how can I fix the second user script ? I'm just curious